# Append data to existing index in elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I need to append the list to already existing data, Here it is,

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
   "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
        "user" : "username",
        "password" : "password",
        "sql": "select * from table where cat_id=1"
        "poll": "24h",
        "strategy": "simple", 
        "scale": 0, 
        "autocommit": true,
        "bulk_size": 5000,
        "max_bulk_requests": 30,
        "bulk_flush_interval": "5s",
        "fetchsize": 100,
        "max_rows": 200000,
        "max_retries": 3,
        "max_retries_wait": "10s",
        "locale": "in",
        "digesting": true,  
}}
```

When i import the above query, 1 million records were inserted into my shards, Now i need to execute another import with same index, my SQL query is vary from the above query, But the data and structure will be the same, my Query like

```
 "sql": "select * from table where module_id>6 AND cat_id != 1"
```

Above query also return same type data, For example above query has 20000 records, Show how can i append the data with above million records, Index and type will be the same.

how can i append the data?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What happens if you replace the initial query with your new query? You should see the 20k records being indexed in the same index, don't you?

Comment: My Expected result count is 1020000, So i need both results with same index, 20k records need to append in previous million records.

Comment: Yes, that's what is going to happen if you let it run. Or do you see something different?

Comment: I have imported using  `http://localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta`, So again when i pass the second query with same URL, i will get created status as false. Data in not appending to the previous one. so `http://localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta`, this one is correct to use second time? or need to change anything